# One Windows Service to access multiple windows application

Tags: windows, wcf

I have a SQL Server database which serves multiple ASP.NET windows applications. They each have their own SiteID to distinguish the data.

I recently realised that it isn't good practice to have multiple applications accessing one database directly and decided I would implement a service to handle all database connections.

All the windows applications and database sit on the same windows 2008 server.

I want to know what kind of service is best for this functionality. windows service?

Comment: "recently realised that it isn't good practice to have multiple applications accessing one database directly" - what makes you say this?  I'm not sure your assumption is sound.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Actually,my problem is,we are using number of windows applications from one server.So,we need to monitor them continuosly.For this,am planning to write one windows application to monitor that logs.Is this correct way?

Comment: Generally speaking, if you have multiple ASP.NET applications, each with different and partitioned data and you can change both the applications AND the database, I would either partition the data using different Instances/Database/Schema (in that order). Forget using a windows service.